# push_back() problems

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to store lines in a file such as

```
15 1 0 0 0 0
33 1 0 0 0 0
29 1 0 0 0 0
18 1 0 0 0 0
25 1 0 0 0 0
```

to become elements of an array. So if I do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std

char* file = "somefile.txt"
FILE *fb_r = fopen(file,"r");
char line[100];
vector <char> lineArr;
string lineElement;
while(fgets(line,256,fb_r){
  sscanf(line, "%s", &lineElement);
  lineArr.push_back(lineElement);  //problem arises here
}
```

but I get the error :
Can't call vector >::pushBack(lineElement)

Comment: have you considered using `iostream` and `getline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your vector contains single `char`s

```
vector <char> lineArr;
```

and it looks like you are trying to push an `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

Change `lineArr` to:

```
vector<string> lineArr;
```

And your `sscanf` is broken too, you can't use it with a `std::string`. The whole thing should probably be:

```
lineArr.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous good answers, please find a fully working program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char* file = "somefile.txt";
    FILE *fb_r = fopen(file,"r");
    char line[100];
    vector<string> lineArr;
    string lineElement;
    while(fgets(line,256,fb_r)) {
      lineElement = line;
      lineArr.push_back(lineElement.substr(0, lineElement.size() -1)); // We here remove the carriage return from the input file which you probably do not want
    }

    for(vector<string>::const_iterator lineIter = lineArr.begin(); lineIter != lineArr.end(); lineIter++) {
       cout << *lineIter << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Which will output, regarding to your input file :

```
15 1 0 0 0 0
33 1 0 0 0 0
29 1 0 0 0 0
18 1 0 0 0 0
25 1 0 0 0 0
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: error says "operator< not defined for vector<string,allocator<string> >::iterator algo.h:453"

Comment: Did you wrote `lineIter < lineArr.end()` instead of  `lineIter != lineArr.end()`, I think it's the cause of your error.